# variable frame rate with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am writing an application for WebGL using Three.js.

I have a fairly simple test app: http://chocolatealbatross.com/ZoomBox .
It uses three.js and physi.js.
It is just a test app to start playing around with these tools.

Most of the time the app runs at 60fps (or thereabouts).  Occasionally, however, it starts off at 30fps.  When this happens, motion seems choppy.  Also, when this happens, the frame rate will eventually drop even further, until the simulation is just plain awful and sometimes it freezes up entirely.

When this does happen, I need to fully kill chrome (pretty much always run in chrome).  Sometimes that fixes the issue and the app runs just fine.  Sometimes I have to restart the machine to reset this behavior.

This is not the only test app I have written and not the only test app with which I've seen this behavior.

I run on a MBP at home and on a Windows machine at work.  Both machines exhibit this behavior.  Neither machine is an awesome "graphics" machine.

There is no correlation between this behavior and other applications running on these systems.  It is independent from any condition I can directly manipulate.

Does anyone know what's going on?  Is there something I can do to safeguard against this happening?  Does this happen to any one else's WebGL/Three app?

The code is all in-line in the HTML file and is only ~300 lines long.  Perhaps I am doing something systematic and stupid?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "occasionally"? I started the app 20 times and it always ran just fine. Maybe it is related to your hardware and/or the amount of heavily loaded tabs that you have started in your browser.

Comment: I wish it were.  I opened it up today and it started out at 14fps!  Choppy.  Nothing else running on my machine.  One other thing, I've seen this same behavior in demo apps not written by me.  Admittedly, I'm on a "business machine" not a "gaming or graphics machine".  I just don't know what to do.

Comment: The state does seem to be sticky.  I just clicked the link I posted above and it ran at 15fps again.  My physical memory is sitting at 42% utilization, CPU at 6 or so.  This is a fresh browser session.  So, what are my diagnostic options?  How do I tell where the slow-down originates?

Comment: also, my machine here at work has two processors with 4 cores each.  I have two (not sure why) NVIDIA Quadro FX 3500 display adapters and I run with three monitors (don't think that matters).  All the processor/cores are 3.2 GHz Xeon X5482's.  Its not a terrible machine though it is the size and weight of a tank.

Comment: To answer your question directly, by "occasionally" I mean: after a fresh reboot it works great.  If I let the app run for a while and do other stuff, the performance will degrade, say, after 5 runs.  Never made it to 20 without seeing issues.

Comment: Lastly, I use a MBP 13" retina at home.  It suffers the same issues.